# как закончить обработку данных с сервера. Netty

Tags: java, netty

При получении данных с сервера не могу вернутся в класс откуда вызывался обработчик. то есть программа зависает в этом классе после получения ответа от сервера и не продолжает выполнять метод в классе откуда был вызван хэндлер.а также надо не просто вернуться туда а вернуть булеву переменную полученную от сервера.

```
public class SmartHouseClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {

    private final BlockingQueue<String> block= new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
    Channel channel;
    static Boolean s;

    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx)   {
        ctx.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object o) throws Exception {
        s=(Boolean)o;
        System.out.println ("Получил "+s);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прокидывайте колбек в класс, который будете вызывать потом.

`static Boolean s;` нельзя писать, иначе у вас `SmartHouseClientHandler`'ы будут перезаписывать эту переменную.

Объявите интерфейс:

```
public interface MyCallBack{
    public void onGetResult(boolean val);
}
```

Передавайте его в конструктор хендлера:

```
public class SmartHouseClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {
    private final BlockingQueue<String> block= new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

    MyCallBack mCallBack;
    public SmartHouseClientHandler (MyCallBack callBack){
         mCallBack = callBack;
    }

    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx)   {
        ctx.close();
    }
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object o) throws Exception {
        s=(Boolean)o;
        System.out.println ("Получил "+s);
        mCallBack(s);
}
```

Класс, в котором инициализируете сервер:

```
public MyClass implements MyCallBack{
      public void onGetResult(boolean val){
           // здесь обработка переменной, полученной в вашем SmartHouseClientHandler 
      }

      public void init(){
         ...
         ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
         ...
         p.addLast(new SmartHouseClientHandler(this));
      }
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, не совсем понял суть, плаваю в этой библиотеке. 
у меня есть два класса один в котором описывается вся структура клиента
'public void runs()   {
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler((new SmartHouseClientInitializer()));
             channel = null;
            channel = b.connect("127.0.0.1", 9989).sync().channel();
             SmartHouseClientHandler handler = channel.pipeline().get(SmartHouseClientHandler.class);'

Comment: Ну вот в ваш `new SmartHouseClientInitializer()` передавайте в конструктор колбек.

Comment: все сделал как вы написали переменную получил, благодарю!)остался только одна проблема работа происходит с формами и при получении переменной (её значение сигнализирует о запуске нового окна) основная форма JavaFx зависает то есть ответ с сервера получаю и такое ощущение что программа до сих пор остается в части работы с сетью, а форма соответственно просто виснет. то есть суть в том как полностью закончить работу с сетью чтобы программа вернулась к остальной работе в данном случае формам.

Comment: @Георгий вряд ли проблема в этом. Хендлеры в Netty асинхронны. Они вряд ли могут заблочить что-то.

Comment: Но в тоже время когда я вызываю метод 
handler.addUser(channel, convert,this); в классе SmartHouseClientHandler приведенном в вопросе. в классе откуда я это делаю(код которого в комментарии) после этой строчки код уже не выполняется значит программа остается в классе SmartHouseClientHandler ?

Comment: `SmartHouseClientHandler ` выполняется не в основном потоке. Быть может в этом дело.

Comment: наверняка в этом.спасибо. я подозревал, что здесь с этим могут быть проблемы.